# how can I get a CL number just generated in P4?

Tags: version-control, perforce

I am quite new to P4 and being a junior dev I am having some issues when trying to automate merges from streams, I am running `p4 merge`, and then `p4 resolve -am`, then I build the project and run some tests and if everything goes well I want to submit otherwise shelve the files so a engineer can go through the conflicts, and manually resolve them and submit. The thing is that the `p4 shelve` command as far as I know needs to have `-c <CL#>` argument, and I do not know how or where I can get the CL number I just generated when running the script. Is there any way to do this? or any documentation that can help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `shelve` command does not require a `-c` argument.

```
C:\Perforce\test\python>p4 help shelve

    shelve -- Store files from a pending changelist into the depot

    p4 shelve [-Af] [-p] [files]
    p4 shelve [-Af] [-a option] [-p] -i [-f | -r]
    p4 shelve [-Af] [-a option] [-p] -r -c changelist#
    p4 shelve [-Af] [-a option] [-p] -c changelist# [-f] [file ...]
    p4 shelve [-As] -d -c changelist# [-f] [file ...]

        ...

        By default, 'p4 shelve' creates a changelist, adds files from the
        user's default changelist, then shelves those files in the depot.
```

If you just ran `p4 merge` and `p4 resolve -am`, the files are open in your default changelist.  Running `p4 shelve` with no arguments will automatically create a new changelist out of those files and shelve it, and it will display the number of the new changelist, so all your script needs to do is print the result of the command.